# const T*& and const T* do not produce ambiguity on function overload

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, overloading, overload-resolution

- Why the following sample code do not produce ambiguity
- Is there any way to call the second version? (If this is not a bug)

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(const int*){cout << "no ref";}
void foo(const int*&){cout << "on ref";}

int main()
{
   int* i=nullptr;
   foo(i);
}
```

---

EDIT:

This

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(const int){cout << "no ref";}
void foo(const int&){cout << "on ref";}

int main()
{
   int i=0;
   foo(i);
}
```

Do produce ambiguity.

---

By the way, remove the const produce ambiguity.

compiler: g++5.3.0 with flag --std=c++14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Why the following sample code do not produce ambiguity

This is not a bug. The parameter's type is `const int*&`, it's a reference to non-const, which can't be bound to object with different type (`int*`). (An implicit convertion is needed, and the produced temporary can't be bound to reference to non-const.)

If you change the parameter's type to reference to const:

```
void foo(const int* const&)
```

Or change the argument's type to `const int*`:

```
const int* i=nullptr;
foo(i);
```

Both will trigger a compile error for ambiguous calling.

> - Is there any way to call the second version? (If this is not a bug)

You can do it through a function pointer, explicitly specifying which one you want to pick up:

```
const int* i=nullptr;
static_cast<void(*)(const int*&)>(&foo)(i);
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. BTW, can I call the second version?

Comment: And can you also tell me why for non-pointer type it do produce ambiguity?

Comment: @appleapple See my edited answer. And what did you mean about "non-pointer type"?

Comment: now I think maybe my question is why `T*` cannot be cast to `const T*&` though.

Comment: @appleapple Glad could help. Well, about why `T*` cannot be bount to `const T*&`, but ok for `const T* const&`, I've tried to explain in the first paragraph. If it's not clear enough please tell me. And references behave differently with pointers, they're not the same thing.